# Exploring web service through WSDL that require authentication

Tags: eclipse, web-services, basic-authentication

I'm working with SOAP based web services that require authentication. I usually use the Eclipse Web Service explorer to explore the offered services but for the services requiring authentication, there does not seem  to be an authentication option and I keep getting the 401 response.

I tried online clients as well. There is one at http://soapclient.com/soaptest.html but it also exhibits the same behavior.

When I try to access the web services through the browser I get the username/password prompt and it works.

I have also tried using https://username:password@webserviceURL. Again, this works in the browser but not in Eclipse or the online SoapClient utility.

Any ideas how I can get do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was pretty trivial in `SoapUI`.

I also found an online client that works with the `http://username:password@webserviceURL` pattern. Its at : http://tools.pointbeing.net/wsdlviewer